# How to change image family for existing image in google cloud compute?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

It looks that unlike labels, image family cannot be changed after the creation of the image. It is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update the cloud labels for an existing image.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a new image from the existing one using gcloud with --source-image

```
gcloud compute images create ${PROD_IMAGE} --family=${PROD_FAMILY} \
  --source-image=${DEV_IMAGE} \
  --source-image-project=${GCP_PROJECT} --project=${GCP_PROJECT}
```

Comment: this is a good way to share images between environments while managing separate image families in each. FYI for a 10GB image, that takes a bit less than 3 minutes to execute.